# Google play console screenshots validations bots

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

So I have had an app in google play for almost 6 months now, the last two month I updated my apps screenshots and from there I begun to get an app rejection each time I update My app.

The last time I fired an appeal and it got accepted so I thought that after the appeal got accepted I won't have any issue when I update my app in the future.

But now I got a new update and it got rejected again with `Not adhering to Unauthorized use of copyrighted content policy`

Those are the screenshots that I created my self.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Now what is the problem, Why do the google auto validation bots not accept those images?
Since the appeal got accepted it means that there should not be any problem.

Is there any way I could validate those images online for google play? and see what's wrong?

Or do you see any problem here that I can't see?

Here is the link to my google app if someone would like to check it out and see if I violate any policy with the description or otherwise.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.novelmanager&gl=SE

Here is the rejection mail I got.

> Hi Developers at Alen Toma, 
> After a recent review, we found that your app NovelManager (com.novelmanager) is not compliant with one or more of our Developer Program Policies. See below for more information about your app’s status and how to correct the issue.
> Issue with your app 
> Your app contains content that doesn't comply with the Unauthorized Use of Copyrighted Content policy.
>
> About Unauthorized Use of Copyrighted Content policy 
> We don’t allow apps that infringe copyright. Modifying copyrighted content may still lead to a violation. Developers may be required to provide evidence of their rights to use copyrighted content.
>
> App status: Rejected 
> Your app has been rejected and wasn't published due to this policy issue. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.
>
> Action required: Submit an updated app for review 
> Here’s what to do to help get your app on Google Play:
>
> 1. Please review the Developer Distribution Agreement and Unauthorized Use of Copyrighted Content policy.
> 2. Make appropriate changes to your app, and be sure to address the issue described above. Also check your app’s store listing for compliance, if applicable.
> 3. Double check that your app is compliant with all other Developer Program Policies.
> 4. Sign in to your Play Console and submit the update to your app.

Comment: I have seen those rejection letters [include a little more detail than that](https://i.imgur.com/G0lbzYV.png). Can you share more than just that one sentence?

Comment: Well That is all I got, When I appealed they only said we accepted your appeal and now you can resubmit your app. When I submitted the app the next month they rejected it again. I did appeal again and I am waiting for replay from them.

Comment: Literally just this one sentence? Not even a greeting and a signature? I dare doubt it.

Comment: read above, I posted the rejection mail I got. The replay mail I got last time from appealing got deleted already. Otherwise why would I lie Or its not like I cant read :)

Comment: My guess is the far left most image contains what seems to be music art, I have no idea what it is. However maybe if you blur out those images within the left most image it might let you pass.

Comment: Its a text to speech image. blur? Would it look good? Could you please do a fast example and if it look good and it pass then I well Give you bounty

Comment: Your rejection letter doesn’t mention screenshots, unlike the one I linked. Maybe it’s the actual content that you’re distributing within the app that is the reason.

Comment: There is many app with similar content. And the content are free translated Chinese novels that are free. I have also applied an appeal once and it was accepted so they have checked the app manually and accepted the appeal. so there is no problem with the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one of the cover images has copyrighted content that could be anything character or logo for example I can write a story that includes superman the story it self not copyrighted but the cover has superman image witch is copyrighted

you can try to blur the images something like this
[image]

Comment: Yes I can understand that, Now how should I fix it. I don't want to remove those cover. Can you edit and blur those cover so that it looks good still ?

Comment: I did try and uplodad the image and a new update, lets wait and see if it gets accepted

Comment: did it help you?

Comment: I published a new update and still waiting for the review.

Comment: The Image I uploaded Worked.

Answer (score 3):

`Not adhering to Unauthorized use of copyrighted content policy`

The `copyrighted content` includes the novels.

Comment: Friend All the novels are free translated novels that exist all over the internet. And I have filed an appeal and after a manually check they have accepted the appeal and published the update. The second time I updated I got rejected to. this rejection I got are from google auto bot checker. Please read the Question before adding an answer. Those rejection Only started after I added those new Images.